# Formik, ReactJs, set focus and remove focus when check and uncheck a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm using a formik custom selector and a normal html checkbox. i need to write code to set focus CustomMultiselect when i check the checkbox and remove the focus when i uncheck.

I tried to use UseRef too. but useRef always gives undefined.

```
const handleAllLicenseCheckBox = prop => {
       if(true)
     // Code to focus the customSELECT
      else 
     //Code to remove focus
```

}

```
<CustomMultiSelect  
 name="question"
 options={options}
 value={valueList}
</CustomMultiSelect>

<input
onClick={() =>
handleCheckBox(props)
}
 type="checkbox"
 name="allcheckbox"
checked={isAllLicenseCheckBox}/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "focus"? Do you mean the select shoud be enabled/disabled by the checkbox?

Comment: I need to focus that field when i tick the checkbox and also remove focus when uncheck the checkbox .

Comment: Could you provide a full code example? (also for your CustomMultiSelect)

Comment: is CustomMultiSelect component created by you? or is it a module you are using for your project? if its the first, then you should use `useimperativehandle` with `forwardRef` to expose the focus and blur function of your input, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: @mamounothman Thank you it is created by me.  When i use useRef current value is alwasy undefined.

Comment: @coding_Lover check this issue https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/pull/478, at the end there is a code to forward the refs to the inner elements of the form.

Answer (score 0):

According to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/keyboard-only-focus-styles/), [`:focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) is the keyboard-only version of `:focus`.

Change

```css
input:focus {...}
```

To

```css
input:focus-visible {...}
```

This supports accessibility by hiding focus on mouse interactions but still show focus on keyboard interactions.

Note [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-visible)